# Earth Engine XEE problem

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

I've recently started using the XEE package and encountered an issue I can't seem to resolve. When I follow this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bdQcEUNrkf3VBxP8KLXCh16c_EakaAu9?usp=sharing), the package works well – cloud masking and even additional band renaming are functioning as expected.

However, when I attempt to work with Sentinel-2 data, these functions no longer work. Specifically, I'm trying to calculate NDVI within Earth Engine and then convert it to an Xarray Dataset. However, when I attempt to plot the first image, I encounter the following error:

> EEException: Image.addBands: Cannot add band 'NDVI' because it doesn't
> appear in srcImg.

This issue isn't limited to visualization. I encounter the same problem when attempting to download images using rioxarray. Furthermore, even when I stick to the original band names and try to plot the first image in a time series, the clouds remain unmasked.

You can find the code in this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bdQcEUNrkf3VBxP8KLXCh16c_EakaAu9?usp=sharing).

Comment: You ran into a XEE bug. I had the same issue and found a workaround. The bug and workaround are filed at https://github.com/google/Xee/issues/88

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the bands you selected and renamed as colours are renamed in the wrong order.
In this function

```
def getSentinel2(aoi, start_date, end_date):
    s2 = get_msi(aoi, start_date, end_date)
    s2 = (s2
        .map(add_cld_shdw_mask)
        .map(apply_cld_shdw_mask)
        .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12'],
               ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])\
        .map(addNDVI)
    )
    return ee.ImageCollection(s2)
```

, you need to replace your `.select()` function with this

```
.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12'],
               ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])
```

I guess your error is probably causing an empty 'NDVI' band.